# Lightest weight IMAP/POP3 server

Tags: linux, email-server

I'm looking for an extremely lightweight mail server to handle IMAP/POP3 connections.  Maildir backend preferably, with multiple authentication modes (SQL, LDAP, etc).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using *nix for your platform, [dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/) is pretty much the standard.  Nearly every unix distro has it available in its ports / package management system.

If you are on Windows, [hmail](http://www.hmailserver.com/) may be a fair choice.

Comment: I've been using dovecot for a couple years now, and it just keeps getting better.  Speedy, resilient, and easy to diagnose.  Great suggestion, +1.